# Throw exception out of RxJava's scope

Tags: rx-java

I am using a library that exposes an RxJava2 API. But my code is not using RxJava (it's actually Kotlin). So I would like to be able to throw exceptions from RxJava to the "outside world", so that my code can catch it.

So I want to do something like this:

```kotlin
fun myFun() {
    someCompletable
        .doOnError { throw it }
        .subscribe()
}
```

And have the user of `myFun()` not know about RxJava at all. The thing is, when RxJava throws an exception, it comes wrapped in a `OnErrorNotImplementedException`, and I don't want that:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | [here is the actual exception]

Is there a way to have `myFun()` throw the actual exception instead of `OnErrorNotImplementedException`?

---

Explaining why the proposed duplicates are irrelevant:

- The first one, "how to return value in RxJava", is absolutely not about exceptions.
- The second one, "rxjava throws OnErrorNotImplementedException", is actually related, but not a duplicate: it does not answer my question, but admittedly looks similar in the sense that it mentions `OnErrorNotImplementedException`.

Comment: What stops you from using the exception cause to move up the stacktrace until you find the exception you like?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50037174/1953590) may be relevant.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar it feels like a hack, and I am not sure how reliable that is (because I am abusing this `OnErrorNotImplementedException`, but I know that depending on how it is triggered, it can be wrapped in at least another one). I want to know if RxJava provides a way to "escape" the RxJava scope or if it just forces everyone to use RxJava in a viral way.

Also please don't rephrase my title if you are not entirely sure that your version is what I want. In this case it is not. I don't want to retrieve the cause, I want to re-throw the underlying exception properly.

Comment: For a library, it is considered good practice to provide exceptions specific to the library. If you don’t like that, you can either wrap it in your own exception or dig out the cause from the library exception. There’s nothing hacky about that.

Comment: I want to translate the exception of the underlying library (the one that exposes an RxJava API). But I don't want to have to unwrap RxJava-specific exceptions that clearly say "you forgot to implement something".

Comment: Yep, you need to block (or convert to coroutine; there are official solutions for that). The reason is that if the Rx code is async in any way, the context of "myFunc" will be gone by that time the sequence gets to an error state. However, using Rx in a blocking fashion is not something that is preferrable, or even necessary. For example, some wrap some blocking code into an async sequence, then block on the outcome -> you could have just put that blocking code straight into your function, without any Rx involvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to call `.blockingAwait()`:

> If the source signals an error, the operator wraps a checked Exception into RuntimeException and throws that. Otherwise, RuntimeExceptions and Errors are rethrown as they are.

With Kotlin and coroutines, RxJava can be converted to a coroutine with `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, like so:

```kotlin
suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    val disposable = someCompletable
        .subscribe({ cont.resume(Unit) }, { e -> cont.resumeWithException(e) })
    cont.invokeOnCancellation { disposable.dispose() }
}
```